# Let $h:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Show there exists a unique tangent field $F$ with $D_qh(v)=F\cdot v$.

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, proof-explanation

The following is an exercise from a set of notes on Differential Geometry asking us to prove a result. I have a few questions about the proof.

---

**Theorem:** Let $S$ be a regular surface and let $h:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Show there exists a unique tangent field $F:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ (that is, a unique differentiable function $F$ tangent to the surface at every point) such that $D_qh(v)=F\cdot v$ (where $\cdot$ denotes the dot producut on $\mathbb{R}^3$).

***Proof:***

Since the restriction of the dot product to $T_qS$ (the tangent plane to $S$ at $q$) is non-degenerate, there exists a unique vector $F(q)\in T_qS$ such that $D_qh(v)=F(q)\cdot v$ for every $v\in T_qS$.

$ \ \ \ $ **Q1**. Why is there such a unique vector?

To show that $F$ is a tangent field, it remains to be shown that $F$ is differentiable. Let $\phi : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a parametrization of $S$.  We'll show the function $\textbf{x}:=F\circ \phi$ is differentiable. Since the partial derivatives $\phi _u, \phi _v$ define a basis for each tangent plane to the surface $S$, there exist functions $\lambda, \mu:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\textbf{x}=\lambda \phi_u+\mu\phi_v$. Therefore to show that $F$ is differentiable it is sufficient to show that (for every parametrization $\phi:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3)$ the functions $\lambda, \mu$ are differentiable.

$ \ \ \ $ **Q2**. Why does the differentiability of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ imply the differentiability of $F$?

Let $E, F, G$ be the coefficients of the first fundamental form of $\phi$. We have that $\textbf{x}\cdot \phi_u=\lambda E+\mu F$ and $\textbf{x}\cdot \phi_v = \lambda F + \mu G$. On the other hand, we have that $\textbf{x}\cdot \phi _u = (h\circ \phi)_u$ and $\textbf{x}\cdot \phi _v = (h\circ \phi)_v$.

$ \ \ \ $ **Q3**. Where do these last two equalities come from?

Since $h:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, both functions $(h\circ \phi)_u$, $(h \circ \phi)_v$ are differentiable. Thus we have

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda \\
\mu
\end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\Delta ^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
G & -F \\
-F & E
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda E + \mu F \\
\lambda F + \mu G
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\frac{1}{\Delta ^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
G & -F \\
-F & E
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
(h\circ \phi)_u \\
(h\circ \phi)_v
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $\Delta ^2 = EG-F^2$. Therefore both functions $\lambda, \mu$ are differentiable.

Comment: Is a surface defined as a smooth $2$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$? If so, include this information into your question.

Comment: @PaulFrost From what I gather they define a _parametrized regular surface_ as a differentiable map $\Phi : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ where $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that for any $q\in U$ we have $d_q$ has rank $2$. A _regular surface_ $S$ is defined as the image of a parametrized regular surface. This definition is not as strict as the one often found in textbooks (e.g. baby do Carmo).

Comment: Okay, but you should include this into your question. I think readers deserve to get all relevant information without reading comments.

Comment: Yes, especially since Q2 is quite tautological under some definitions, and possibly nontrivial under other definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Note that $D_qh: T_qS \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a linear functional on $T_qS$. As stated, the dot product is non degenerate at $T_qS$, this mans that the linear map
$$T_qS \longrightarrow\mathbb (T_qS)^*$$
$$u \mapsto u \cdot(-)$$
where $u\cdot(v) = u \cdot v \in \mathbb R$ is an isomorphism. Since $D_qh \in (T_qS)^*$, we get that there is a unique $u \in T_qS$ such that $u\cdot(-)=D_qh$.

Q2: If $\mathbf x = \lambda \phi_u + \mu \phi_v$, then $\mathbf x$ is smooth if, and only if, $\lambda,\mu$ are smooth. Note that  $F=\mathbf x \circ \phi^{-1}$, thus if $\mathbf x$ is smooth then so is $F$.

Q3: The first one comes from the definition of  the first fundamental form. For the second one, using the chain rule we get that $$(h \circ \phi)_u = D_{\phi(u)}h (\phi_u) = F(\phi(u)) \cdot \phi_u=\mathbf x \cdot \phi_u$$
where we are using the definitions of $F$ and $\mathbf x$.